# How to input test data set in this processing code?

Tags: dataset, processing, minim, brain-computer-interface

I'm a undergraduate Biomedical Engineering , only a beginner in coding. I was trying to understand this BCI code written in processing and wanted to input an EEG eye movement dataset rather than the microphone jack input . I can't figure out how to do this.
For more info on the project please visit : https://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-EEG-and-ECG-Circuit/

The code is here : https://github.com/tapan80048/Brain-computer-interface

Thanks.